# Karma unable to launch IE on VSO build agent(build server)

Tags: internet-explorer, karma-jasmine, azure-pipelines, build-server

It is a in house build server. We are running VSO build agent on Window Server 2012 and it has IE 11 installed on it.

VSO build agent is running under 'Network Service' user.

On the unit testing build step, Karma is able to launch chrome but not IE.

**Error**

```
2017-06-14T18:10:38.5588660Z [33m14 06 2017 14:10:38.557:WARN [launcher]: [39mIE have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
2017-06-14T18:10:38.7008770Z [32m14 06 2017 14:10:38.699:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start IE again (1/2).
2017-06-14T18:11:38.7030837Z [33m14 06 2017 14:11:38.702:WARN [launcher]: [39mIE have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
2017-06-14T18:11:38.8830954Z [32m14 06 2017 14:11:38.882:INFO [launcher]: [39mTrying to start IE again (2/2).
2017-06-14T18:12:38.8953023Z [33m14 06 2017 14:12:38.884:WARN [launcher]: [39mIE have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
2017-06-14T18:12:39.0743168Z [31m14 06 2017 14:12:39.074:ERROR [launcher]: [39mIE failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

I even tried the suggestion in [Karma fails to launch IE on Team City build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31029087/karma-fails-to-launch-ie-on-team-city-build)

Still no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you try that suggestion? What're steps that you log on the machine by using Network Service?

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is that you can change the build service account (e.g. your account):

1. Open Local Services
2. Double click the build service
3. Select Log On
4. Choose This account and specify a account.

Comment: I tried Local System with option 'Allow service to interact with desktop'. No luck. I even tried with system admin account and even that didn't work.

Comment: @Sundeep Do you restart service after changing account? Restart service is required. On the other hand, try to turn off IE Enhanced Security Configuration.

Comment: Yes. I did restart service after changing the account. I will try turning off the enhanced security. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just checked the setting on the server. IE Enhanced security configuration is turned off.

Comment: @Sundeep What's the result if you run the test with IE on build agent server manually? You can try to repair IE.

Comment: @Sundeep Try to repair IE and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the build agent in [interactive mode](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#choose-interactive-or-service-mode) instead of service mode.